# Command windows-7-x64 is not recognized

Tags: command, windows-7-x64

I would use this command with windows-7-x64 :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder compass create MyTheme
```

but windows return :

```
'C:\Program' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe,
un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes
```

How to do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compass create C:\Path\to\MyFolder\MyTheme

the first word is always the command that is being run followed by the parameters. 'compass' is being run and the rest are the parameters.

note: if you're not running the console from the folder that contains the compass executable you will need to add the folder to the Path environment variable.

you can view the documentation here that outlines the correct syntax of the command to create a project https://teamtreehouse.com/library/compass-basics/getting-started-with-compass/creating-a-compass-project

Comment: Great ! thank you for answer et documentation. I understood :)

Comment: I was mistaken about path and I forgot to do `gem update --system`